# Multiply a generated array by value x and find the average

Tags: arrays, c, average, element, multiplication

this is my current code that I am working with:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
   //1
    int NUM[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int i,j,k;
    int len = sizeof NUM / sizeof * NUM;

    //3
    int ODD[len];
    int EVEN[len];

    //4
    j = 0;
    k = 0;

    //5
    int sum = 0;
    int average;

    for(i = 0; i<10 ; i++){
        //5
        if(NUM[i]%2 == 0){
            EVEN[j] = NUM[i];
            j++;
        }else{
            ODD[k] = NUM[i];
            k++;
        }
    }


    //6
    printf("Even numbers : ");
    for(i = 0;i<j; i++){
        printf("%d ",EVEN[i]);
    }

    printf("\nOdd numbers : ");
    for(i = 0;i<k; i++){
        printf("%d ",ODD[i]);
    }

    printf("\nFrequency of EVEN array is :");
    for(i = 0;i<j; i++){
        sum = sum + EVEN[i];
        average = sum / j;
        printf("%d ",average);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Output:

```
Even numbers : 2 4 6 8 10 
Odd numbers : 1 3 5 7 9 
Frequency of EVEN array is :0 1 2 4 6
```

What I am trying to do is multiply the generated EVEN[i] array by 0.02, then find the mean/average of that new array and inverse it. In formula terms it would be 1 /mean(EVEN[i]*=0.02). I am stuck on manipulating the EVEN[i] array with the operations mentioned.

Edit 1:
my code for average:

```
    double Arr[i];
    for(i=0;i<j;i++){
    Arr[i] = EVEN[i]*0.02;
    printf("%f ", Arr[i]);
    }

    printf("\nAverage of EVEN array is :");
    size_t n = sizeof(Arr)/ sizeof (Arr[0]);
    for(i = 0;i<j; i++){
        sum = sum + Arr[i];
    }
        average = sum / n;
        // printf("%d ",n);
        printf("%f ",average);
        return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Average of EVEN array is :0.000000
```

Not sure why it is displaying 0.

Comment: Doesn't look like C! C doesn't support dynamic array size when you declare them as `int ODD[len];`

Comment: @ShipluMokaddim: that's a *new* C feature since C99, called VLA :)

Comment: You need `double EVEN[]` not `int`

Comment: @pmg: "new" :-) New-borns of that age are now writing their own programming languages.

Comment: I must be so old. The **99** in C99 is 22 years old already!

Answer (score 0):

For new array which is made by Even[i]*0.02 term

```
double Arr[j];
for(let i=0;i<j;j++){
    Arr[i] = Even[i]*0.02;
}
```

Now for inverse array, you can simply do

```
double Arr2[j];
for(let i=0;i<j;j++){
    Arr2[i] = 1/Arr[i];
}
```

Or if you want do perform this directly, you can do

```
double Arr[j];
for(let i=0;i<j;j++){
    Arr[i] = 1/(Even[i]*0.02);
}
```

Or am i missing something from your question?

Comment: How would I go about finding the average of Arr[i]? When I tried in my code it gave me an array whereas it should just be a singular value.

Comment: @AshtonStark just make a new variable, and divide the sum of arr by its length, so basically take sum=0, add arr[i] to sum for each i =0 to N , then just divide sum by N to get average

Comment: That is what I did in my code above but I get an array instead of a singular value

Comment: @AshtonStark that is not what you did in your code above. You probably wanted to close the block `}` right after `sum = sum + EVEN[i];` instead after `printf`

Comment: @Gerhardh I have fixed this, yet I still am getting an average of 0.

Comment: @AshtonStark looking at your update in the question, this is because you are using wrong types: `printf("%f ",average);` You should get a compiler warning for passing an  `int` while format specifier `%f` requires a `double` argument. You should change type of `average`.